# Iframe vs AngularJS

Tags: single-page-application

In a project, I need to use single page application using Cordova framework.

The best option I found is AngularJS.

However some people suggested to use iframe instead.

I have googled through to check for best option. But I could not find any info.

Can anyone suggest which one is best choice. If so, why?

(Please don't term it as vague. It's very important thing for me)

Comment: use angular with ionic framework, thats gives u rich look and flexibility

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you check out [jQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/)

> jQuery Mobile is a HTML5-based user interface system designed to make
>   responsive web sites and apps that are accessible on all smartphone,
>   tablet and desktop devices.

It lets you create a really nice seamless web experience that has a very 'native-app' vibe.

It works really well with Cordova! I've used it in many mobile apps to date. Just drop the jQuery Mobile project in your www folder and build your platforms!

Answer (score 0):

They're completely different approaches and ultimately it would depend on the application. Generally for web based projects iframes are not generally considered best practise and should be avoided. The story may be different for Cordova applications but I figure it's unlikely.

AngularJS can be great for many applications but can be a little involved to learn at first. If you have a solid understanding of JavaScript it may be worth learning as it can make creating applications in HTML5 a lot simpler.

For a simpler application it may be easier to avoid a framework entirely.

Framework choice should ultimately come down to what's the best fit for the application you're developing - there is no blanket solution for every application. I'd suggest researching a few frameworks and seeing what's the best fit for your application.

A few to consider (a starting point not a complete list):
Javascript:

- AngularJS,
- ReactJS
- jQuery (jQuery, jQuery UI, jQuery Mobile)

CSS (may contain some JS/UI elements also):

- Bootstrap
- Foundation